# How to configure bootstrap for php

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I just tried to start with php and bootstrap but for some reason my website does not recognize bootstrap. It does not use it's design but rather simple html. This is how my
index.php looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-kjU+l4N0Yf4ZOJErLsIcvOU2qSb74wXpOhqTvwVx3OElZRweTnQ6d31fXEoRD1Jy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is how my page looks which I want to use as a component:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputUser" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">User Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUser" name="user" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign in" name="submit" class="btn btn- 
         primary"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Could someone look at my error and tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: What do the browser developer tools tell you?  Can the browser load Bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap is just CSS and javascript, so has nothing to do with PHP. Open up your browser's developer console and look for information there, and view the source to make sure everything is formatted correctly. Does the form show up between the body tags?

Comment: @stdunbar how do I do that? Where in the console can I see this?

Comment: @aynber yes the form is loaded between the body tags with the correct classes

Comment: When I open the console and switch to sources tab. I can only see my about-us.php is that the error?

Comment: By the way, there's a newline showing here on `btn- primary`, which breaks the CSS class

Comment: What errors are in the console tab?

Comment: "_which I want to use as a component_" Try placing your form directly inside the HTML you posted above your form. How are they related? What is the first block of code? There doesn't seem to be much inside the `<body>`. How/where do you load the component?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post with exactly what you see when you right-click on the page and click on View Page Source? Is all of the formatting missing, or only part of it. You mention an error, what error?

Comment: Your code is working fine (without that newline inside `btn-primary` class): https://jsfiddle.net/ybe2mgcn/

Comment: It's literally work for me !. can you say what error you saw on your console ?

Comment: I wanted to have my css sources at one place instead of copieng them to every php file I am using for web development. Like in angular with package json is that not possible?

Comment: I thought of having one central place with every src/css and scripts I need to have and the other classes are using them

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, nothing is wrong.

You may want to check your internet connection and  perhaps browser. It works quite okay upon trying it here. If it persists, try downloading the bootstrap zip package, open it in your project directory and link it to your page manually.